# Getting a segmentation fault when initializing an array of structs

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm working on refactoring an old code base in C. I have this struct:

```
struct example_opt_t
{                      
    const char *name;  
    const char *value;
};
```

and I want to initialize my options (name, value) so that I can pass it to an `init` function.

This is the `init()` declaration:

```
struct lh_ctx_t *init( const struct example_clb_t *callbacks, void *user_data, const struct example_opt_t *options ) {
```

And this is my attempt to initialize `options`:

```
const struct example_opt_t my_options[2] = {
    (struct example_opt_t){
        "option1_name",
        "option1_value",
    },
    (struct example_opt_t){"option2_name",
                      "option2_value"},
};
```

But I'm getting a segfault. What am I doing wrong here?

[UPDATE]:

`init` at some point calls the function below:

```
if ( example_strcasecmp( option->name, name ) ) return false;
```

the body of which is:

```
int example_strcasecmp( const char *s1, const char *s2 ) {

 int diff;

 if ( s1 == NULL  ||  s2 == NULL ) return 0;
 /* I'm getting a segfault at the line below*/
 do { diff = example_lowercase(s1++) - example_lowercase(s2++); } 
 while ( diff == 0  &&  s1[-1] != '\0' );

 return diff;
}
```

And `example_lowercase` is:

```
int example_lowercase( const char *s ) {

 return tolower( *(const unsigned char *)s );
}
```

The weird thing is that, I'm still getting a segfault but now I cannot see the exact line this is generated since the gdb output is the below:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000055aace859039 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055aace859039 in ?? ()
#1  0x000055aacf4b6268 in ?? ()
#2  0x000055aace85671a in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffe39cd0e34 in ?? ()
#4  0x000055aacf4b6268 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffe39cd0f40 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007ffe39cd0f20 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007ffe39cd0e34 in ?? ()
#8  0x000055aace857f6f in ?? ()
#9  0x000055aacf4b6268 in ?? ()
#10 0x5d4ca731752bb200 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007ffe39cd0f20 in ?? ()
#12 0x000055aacf4b6268 in ?? ()
#13 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you per chance returning a pointer to a local array?

Comment: OT: The `(struct example_opt_t)` casts are useless, you should remove them.

Comment: I guess your `init()` function has some way of telling how many `struct example_opt_t*` the `options` parameter is pointing at ?

Comment: "*I'm getting a segfault.*" in which line of code?

Comment: Hello everybody and thanks for taking the time to help me out. I've updated my example with more details, as well as where I'm getting the segfault.

Comment: `s1[-1] != '\0'` -  and what if `strlen(s2) < strlen(s1)`?! `option->name, name` - does `option->name` and `name` point to valid memory? Please post an [MCVE]. `now I cannot see the exact line` did you compile with optimization disabled and debugging enabled?

Comment: @kingJulian Are you trying to initialize the options in some function which is not `main()`?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda, no it's in main. Given the `example_opt_t`, is my initialization correct?

Comment: Having a bounty won't get people to answer your question if you don't give us enough information to do so.  Please update your post with a [mcve] that others can compile and run *as is* to get the same problem you have.

Comment: @dbush Unfortunately, due to work constraints, I cannot provide more info. Tbh, I thought the problem would be with the pointers initialization or with `example_strcasecmp`.

Comment: @kingJulian That's where the "minimal" part of an MVE comes from.  It doesn't have to be your entire program, just a small piece that's large enough to recreate the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have posted @dbush. The `init` function calls `example_strcasecmp` at some point. Up until then there are some random `if` checks that do not apply to our case.

Comment: @kingJulian  No it's not.  You've given us a few separated snippets here and there with a vauge description of how things get called.  You show the actual call to `example_strcasecmp` but you don't show how the arguments are declared or set.  `example_strcasecmp` doesn't look like it has a problem, so the issue is in the code you haven't shown us.  Again, you need to post just enough code that someone can cut-and-paste it without modification, compile and run it, and see the same problem you do.

Comment: Also, if you haven't done so already run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: To reiterate in case you missed it: you should post the minimum code needed (in a single snippet) that someone can copy/paste without modification, compile and run, and see the same problem you do. That is the essence of a [mcve].

Comment: `#0  0x000055aace859039 in ?? ()`, when you get this kind of info. It's most likely the stack is corrupt.  Is there some thing like `memcpy` in init before calling `example_strcasecmp`?  An you could just use `strcasecmp` to replace `example_strcasecmp`.

Comment: Didn't do that for a long time but I  am pretty sure you should Init you struct with malloc or something like this

Comment: @randomeval, no there isn't any memcpy before calling `example_strcasecmp` just some irrelevant `if` clauses that do not apply to our case (and cannot publicly share)

Comment: @kingJulian, I still think SIGSEGV is caused by stack overflow. So I suggest you change local variable definition in `init` function to `static` type. This will make all local variable's memory in data section. It will still give you SIGSEGV, but gdb maybe can show you what's really wrong, not just some `?? ()`.

Answer (score 1):

When strlen(s1) > strlen(s2) you are running past the end of s2 into unmapped memory.

Change this -

```
while ( diff == 0  &&  s1[-1] != '\0' );
```

To this -

```
while ( diff == 0  && s1[-1] != '\0' && s2[-1] != '\0' );
```

And confirm whether that fixes your problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't fix it. `gdb` says that the problem is within `example_lowercase`, so I'm wondering if the way I'm initializing `options` may cause a problem in the `example_lowercase` function.

Comment: It seems to me that if `L1 = strlen(s1)` and `L2 = strlen(s2)`, and `L1 > L2`, then when you reach the null byte at the end of `s2`, you have a non-null byte in `s1[L2]`, so the difference will not be zero and the loop will terminate (and without referencing beyond the end of `s2`).